# Correct Data Structure for Collection with Multiple Mutable Look-Up Properties

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, data-structures

If I have an in memory collection of 5,000 or more objects of type `SampleObject`

```
class SampleObject {
  ...
  Date getLastRefreshDate()
  Status getCurrentStatus()
}
```

I want to quickly get the sub-list of objects with a refresh date that is older than some value, and also be able to quickly get the objects with a certain status, what data-structure/algorithm would be useful?  Is iterating the list and doing comparisons fast enough?  What if the list grows to 25,000 or more?

Answer (score 2):

A `TreeMap<Date, SampleObject>` could do the job of getting "older than" a certain date, pretty easily -- you'd just use `headMap` to get all the objects older than some value.

You'd need a separate `Map<Status, List<SampleObject>>` (or, if you can use third-party libraries, a Guava `Multimap`) to track objects with some particular status, though, but I think a second data structure is inevitable anyway if you're not willing to pay for linear search.

Answer (score 1):

The [NavigableSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) and [NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) classes offer methods to do just that.

`NavigableSet` already offer methods like `headSet` and `tailSet` to get all elements before or after a other given element. You could use your date criteria as a `Comparator` if not already povided as a natural order for your `SampleObject` class.

Besides other useful methods like `lower`, `floor`, `ceiling`, and `higher`.

Likewise `NavigableMap` offer similar methods like headMap and tailMap to do exactly the same kind of slicing.

Answer (score 0):

> get the sub-list of objects with a refresh date that is older than some value, and also be able to quickly get the objects with a certain status

Sounds like a *k*-dimensional range or search problem. Your options include:

- [a *k-d*-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)
- [a range tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree)

You might be able to get away with lineary access via a sorted structure, if you mostly return data in one dimension only.